# Get Data from firebase one child to another

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm pretty much new to angular and firebase. I would like to ask on how to I query from firebase child to another? like this structure of the db: how can I query tasks...

[image: query tasks]

in my `task.service.ts` I have written this code:

```
getAll(){
return this.db.list('/users' + uid + '/tasks');
}
```

but it says `[TS] Cannot find uid`.

sorry I know this is pretty much basic, I'm just a beginner please bear with me.

And thank you so much!

**Edit** - code structure

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
 import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

 @Injectable() 
 export class TaskService { 
    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { } 
    //get data from database 
    getAllTask(){ 
      return this.db.list('/users/' + this.uid + '/tasks'); 
    } 
  }
```

Comment: that should be `this.uid`

Comment: what do u mean? as of now I can get and display the data from users but when I try to get data in tasks I got a problem.

Comment: @Hareesh I tried using it but it says property uid does not exist.

Comment: try `this.db.list('/users/' + this.uid + '/tasks');` you missed a slash

Comment: @Hareesh still I got an error the property uid does not exist in my tasks.service.ts

Comment: show the code to get `uid`. may be your are not getting it correctly

Comment: @Hareesh i have updated my post and included my code.

Comment: you need to pass the `uid` from where you calling the `.getAllTask(uid)`, then you can use `this.db.list('/users/' + uid + '/tasks')`

Comment: put your code in a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) and share, so others can debug and suggest.